# VC dimension of perpendicular lines classifier

Tags: machine-learning

I was learning about VC dimension, and I saw an example in the ["Introduction to Machine learning"](https://dl.matlabyar.com/siavash/ML/Book/(Adaptive%20computation%20and%20machine%20learning)%20Ethem%20Alpaydin-Introduction%20to%20machine%20learning-MIT%20Press%20(2004).pdf) that the VC dimension of a rectangle is 4. I'm just curious about VC-dimension of two perpendicular lines. I try to shatter some points but I'm not sure about it. I think It should be 2,3 or 4. But could find the exact n.[image]

Comment: it is not hard to show that no set of 5 points can be shattered by this family of classifiers using the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: @StratosFair
Can you explain more about it? I couldn't find similar examples to prove using pigeonhole principle.

Comment: I just added an answer, by I encourage you to do a drawing : what happens when you try to classify 5 points (or more) wiht this family of classifiers ?

Answer (score 2):

For the VC dimension of a classifier to be at least $n$, we just need to give a single example of a set of points that it can shatter. This is an example of a set of 4 points that the perpendicular lines classifier can shatter:

$$\{ (0,1), (1,0), (0,-1), (-1,0) \}$$

For each possible assignment of labels, I give a pair of perpendicular lines that correctly classifies all points:

- YYYY/NNNN: $y=2$, $x=2$
- YNNN/NYYY: $y=0.5$, $x=2$
- NYNN/YNYY: $y=2$, $x=0.5$
- NNYN/YYNY: $y=-0.5$, $x=2$
- NNNY/YYYN: $y=2$, $x=-0.5$
- YYNN/NNYY: $y=-x$, $y=x-2$
- NYYN/YNNY: $y=x$, $y=x-2$
- YNYN/NYNY: $y=x$, $y=-x$

Thus, its VC dimension must be at least 4.

Comment: thank you!
Why it is not 5? is there any way to prove that it is not more than 4? because if we can every single number like 4,5,6,..

Answer (score 1):

Your drawing and inavda's answer already show that the VC dimension of your family of classifiers (hypothesis space) is at least $4$.

Showing that the VC dimension is strictly less than $5$ is also pretty straightforward by doing a drawing, but here is a more formal proof : fix $5$ points $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\} $ in the Euclidean plane $\mathbb R^2$, and let $C$ be any classifier in your hypothesis space.

By definition of the hypothesis space, there is a partition of $\mathbb R^2$ into four quadrants $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ (the regions delimited by the two perpendicular lines) such that $C$ assigns the same class to all $x$ belonging in the same quadrant. More formally, for all $1\le i\le 4$ :
$$x\in A_i \implies C(x) = \varepsilon_i \tag1$$
Where $\varepsilon_i\in\{-1,+1\}$ is fixed (it depends on $C$ only).

Now we have $5$ points in the plane $x_1,\ldots,x_5$, and the plane is partitioned in $4$ disjoint subsets $A_1,\ldots,A_4$, so (by the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)) there exists an index $i_0 \in [\!|1,4|\!]$ such that $x_i$ and $x_j$ belong in $A_{i_0}$ for some $i,j \in [\!|1,5|\!]$ $i\ne j$ (in other words, one of the quadrant must contain at least two distinct $x_i$'s, very clear with a drawing).

Now simply assign to $x_i$ the class $-1$ and to $x_j$ the class $+1$, and you see from equation $(1)$ that $C$ can't properly classify these two points.
Because $C$ was taken arbitrarily, it follows that no classfier in this hypothesis space can shatter this set of $5$ points, and because the set of points was also arbitrary we conclude that no set of $5$ points can be shattered by this family of classifiers, hence the hypothesis space has VC dimension strictly less than 5.

Conclusion : The VC dimension of the hypothesis space is strictly less than $5$ and at least $4$, so it is equal to $4$.